# help with adding an url href

Tags: iphone, html

i am confused about how i can add a link to the following code

```
    onReady: function() {
    new Ext.TabPanel({
        fullscreen: true,
        type: 'dark',
        sortable: true,
        items: [{
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html: '1',
            cls: 'card1'
```

to be able to directly load a url when i click the Tab 1. This code is from the sencha touch template. I want the htm part to be able to load a url when that tab is selected. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `autoLoad config option` for this.

You can try,

```
  onReady: function() {
new Ext.TabPanel({
    fullscreen: true,
    type: 'dark',
    sortable: true,
    items: [{
        title: 'Tab 1',
       autoLoad   : {
                       url :youryrl,
                       scripts:true,
                        callback: function(){ yourcallbackfunction(); }
                     },
```

for detailed documentation, refer

http://examples.extjs.eu/

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext/docs/output/Ext.TabPanel.html

[http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:TabPanel_Basics](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aTabPanel_Basics)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i didnt really find the appropriate usage of autoLoad in any except the second document. do u mind explaining how this would be used?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check it now. Also, i have added extjs documentation link.

Comment: in my items would i use the autoload: 'url' or would i need to say autoLoad 'url:www.google.com'

Comment: For your case, targetUrl will be replaced by the url whose content you want to load in the tab. eg: If you want to load content of google then you can use goole url. In short, just replace targetUrl with your required url.

Comment: i am sorry i cant get this to work. as u see above i have items. when i try and add the autoLoad it doesnt work at all. is there any iframe alternative?

Comment: @Alx: i have edited the answer, please check now. It should work for you.